# iOS - variable not in scope when application moves to background?

Tags: ios, scope, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary declared as follows in my Sample.h file -

```
@interface Sample : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UIActionSheetDelegate , UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tagState;
}   

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableDictionary *tagState;
@end
```

in my Sample.m file, I populate values in the init function, as well as the viewWillAppear. However, when the application moves to the background and I try accessing the dictionary in the viewWillDisappear method, the map appears to not hold any values.

How do I keep those values and access them in that method? Am I missing something?